# MS Graph: Cannot interact with deviceEnrollmentConfigurations using app registration

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, intune

For some reason I have become unable to interact with the **deviceManagement/deviceEnrollmentConfigurations** MS graph endpoint using a registered application.
According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/intune-shared-deviceenrollmentconfiguration-list?view=graph-rest-beta), this endpoint requires the `DeviceManagementServiceConfig.ReadWrite.All` scope, which is assigned to the application.

When attempting any request (GET/POST/whatever), the endpoint returns HTTP/403 with the following error message:

```
Application is not authorized to perform this operation as called in app only context but does not have application permissions configured.
```

This has worked previously using the very same app registration, but I guess microsoft did something to this endpoint sometime this month...?

I've been wondering if some of you guys also have had issues with this endpoint recently?

Comment: You can refer to similar issues: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/15952 , https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/11293 and https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/9162

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [***MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/intune-shared-deviceenrollmentconfiguration-list?view=graph-rest-beta) ,
***We can not use this under beta version which is subject to change , in Production its not supported for now.***

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I experience the same problem with the production API (https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0). Just spoke to Microsoft. They admit there is a problem with this specific API endpoint (/deviceManagement/deviceEnrollmentConfigurations). The development team is working on it and they expect a solution by the end of the next month.

As of the week of March 21, release 2203 has been released and the problem seems to be solved.

Comment: Thanks for your comment!  
Guess it wasn't just me then.  

Seeing as this has been an issue for some time now, let's just hope that MS can resolve this soon.